# Here is some Keras code. I don't understand what "(x)" means

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

```
output_tensor = layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')(x)
```

Here are some codes in keras. I don't understand what `(x)` means in context of the invoked method. Can anyone help me?

Comment: it means function call with value `x`

Comment: Check the doc: https://keras.io/models/model/

Answer (score 1):

`layers.Dense` returns a callable object, which you then call giving `x` as input.

The `Dense` function creates the layer, and the layer is something that must be given something else as input. This "something else" is specified when you call the layer itself.

Maybe this snippet will help:

```
In [1]: from keras import layers
Using TensorFlow backend.

In [2]: x = layers.Input((1, ))

In [3]: l = layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')

In [4]: callable(l)
Out[4]: True

In [5]: l(x)
Out[5]: <tf.Tensor 'dense_1/Softmax:0' shape=(?, 10) dtype=float32>
```